# Quickest way to convert Bootstrap website to IOS app with Cordova?

Tags: iphone-app, bootstrap

We have a large database backed Bootstrap/jQuery website. The website is not a single page application (we build each page server-side), but is responsive and provides a decent mobile experience. We'd like to create an app, and we'd like to use as much of the existing HTML/javascript as possible. It seems like Cordova is the way to go. But Cordova wants a single page app. What's the best way to convert our existing site to do this? We're hoping to not have to rearchitect the entire site or switch to a new framework if possible, and are ambivalent about converting our existing web site into a single page app. Is this possible? The server/backend is all in Go, if that matters.